# Contact form with php

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I made this code but when i receive the email it just says
"from:
 message:"
it doesn't include my message here are the 2 files

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><title>Contact</title></head>
  
  <body bgcolor="DCDCDC">
    <h1><center><b><u>Contact</u></b></center></h1>
    <center>
      <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
        <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
        <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
        <p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="send"><input type="reset" value="clear">
      </form>
    </center>
    
    <p><center><a href="index.php">Return</a></center></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the PHP

```
<?php
  $name = $_post['name'];
  $email = $_post['email'];
  $message = $_post['message'];
  $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
  $recipient = "admin@benpaterson35.netne.net";
  $subject = "Contact Form";
  $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
  mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die      ("Error!");
  echo "Thank you!";
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: The param 3 is the content and you'r sending `$formcontent` http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

Comment: try using `$_POST` instead of `$_post`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `$_post` is in lowercase. All `$_XXX` are to be uppercase and `$_POST` as well.

So your `$name` and `$email` are actually empty. Try to echo them and see if that's why.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

The reason why the code requires them to be uppercase is that when you set standards and enforce them, you have fewer errors in
the code, and you can find those errors earlier in the development process.

Comment: PS: `<!DOCTYPE html>` should also be in uppercase.

Comment: Thank you changed it didn't realize how important it being uppercase was thank you,

Comment: Sure @Ben! Feel free to set my answer as the right one if you feel it is. :D (by clicking the "Check")

Comment: `<!doctype>` doesn't matter which case it's in. However, `$_POST` is what is referred to as a superglobal http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and that is why it must be in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your are calling the wrong global post variable. It should be $_POST (all uppercase), not $_post.

Answer (score 0):

Case can be the problem as someone already said it here

```
<INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE ="username" NAME = "formElement_name">
```

To get the value use:

```
 $Your_Variable = $_POST['formElement_name'];
```

Before sending be sure your are really getting the value that you need

```
$message= $_POST['message'];
print ($message);
```